# Visual Studio 2008 - Editing the Project Solution File to Fix the project's Directory Structure

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-sourcesafe, directory-structure

Either VS2008 or Source Safe messed up the file structure for a program I found on Source Safe. Currently the solution files are only located under Documents and Settings\mjones\MyDocuments\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SeminarMailings\SeminarMailings\ and all the coding files are under COIN\Development\SeminarMailings\ and Documents and Settings\mjones\MyDocuments\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SeminarMailings\SeminarMailings\Development\

Question: 
How would I edit the solution file in such a way that it will still load if clean up the unecessary directories by putting  all the solution files under COIN and the code files under COIN\SeminarMailings and deleting the rest of the folders (duplicate data).

Background: 
Here's the current directory structure w/ the coding files in the right window pane:

[image: Fixing VS2010 File Structure in Solution File]

Here are the files that I need references in the file's solution under VS2008.

[image: Fixing VS2010 File Structure in Solution File]

Here's the code for the solution file:

```
    Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00
    # Visual Studio 2008
    Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "SeminarMailings",                        "..\..\..\..\..\..\Development\SeminarMailings", "{2951C6A1-AF82-40C6-9DD8-93E35E5135F6}"

ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
    SccProjectName = ""$/SeminarMailings.root/SeminarMailings", CKLAAAAA"
    SccAuxPath = ""
    SccLocalPath = "..\.."
    SccProvider = "MSSCCI:Microsoft Visual SourceSafe"
    TargetFramework = "3.5"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/SeminarMailings"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "..\..\..\..\..\..\Development\SeminarMailings\"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\SeminarMailings\"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/SeminarMailings"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "..\..\..\..\..\..\Development\SeminarMailings\"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\SeminarMailings\"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "False"
    VWDPort = "4951"
    DefaultWebSiteLanguage = "Visual C#"
        EndProjectSection
            EndProject

            Global
        GlobalSection(SourceCodeControl) = preSolution
    SccNumberOfProjects = 2
    SccProjectName0 = \u0022$/SeminarMailings.root/SeminarMailings\u0022,\u0020CKLAAAAA
    SccLocalPath0 = ..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..
    SccProvider0 = MSSCCI:Microsoft\u0020Visual\u0020SourceSafe
    SccProjectFilePathRelativizedFromConnection0 = Documents\u0020and\u0020Settings\\mjones\\My\u0020Documents\\Visual\u0020Studio\u00202008\\Projects\\SeminarMailings\\
    SccWebProject1 = true
    SccProjectUniqueName1 = ..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\Development\\SeminarMailings
    SccLocalPath1 = ..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..
    SccProjectFilePathRelativizedFromConnection1 = Development\\SeminarMailings\\
    SccProjectEnlistmentChoice1 = 2
EndGlobalSection
GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
    Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
EndGlobalSection
GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
    {2951C6A1-AF82-40C6-9DD8-93E35E5135F6}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    {2951C6A1-AF82-40C6-9DD8-93E35E5135F6}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
EndGlobalSection
GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
    HideSolutionNode = FALSE
EndGlobalSection
    EndGlobal
```

Any suggestions would be welcomed!

Thanks for looking!

Comment: any suggestions? is there something i need to make more clear with this example?

Answer (score 1):

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00
# Visual Studio 2008
Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "SeminarMailings",                        "..\..\..\..\..\..\Development\SeminarMailings", "{2951C6A1-AF82-40C6-9DD8-93E35E5135F6}"

ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
SccProjectName = ""$/SeminarMailings.root/SeminarMailings", CKLAAAAA"
SccAuxPath = ""
SccLocalPath = "..\.."
SccProvider = "MSSCCI:Microsoft Visual SourceSafe"
TargetFramework = "3.5"
Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/SeminarMailings"
Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "..\..\..\..\..\..\Development\SeminarMailings\"
Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\SeminarMailings\"
Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
Release.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/SeminarMailings"
Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "..\..\..\..\..\..\Development\SeminarMailings\"
Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\SeminarMailings\"
Release.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
Release.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
Release.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
Release.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "False"
VWDPort = "4951"
DefaultWebSiteLanguage = "Visual C#"
    EndProjectSection
        EndProject

        Global
    GlobalSection(SourceCodeControl) = preSolution
SccNumberOfProjects = 2
SccProjectName0 = \u0022$/SeminarMailings.root/SeminarMailings\u0022,\u0020CKLAAAAA
SccLocalPath0 = ..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..
SccProvider0 = MSSCCI:Microsoft\u0020Visual\u0020SourceSafe
SccProjectFilePathRelativizedFromConnection0 = Documents\u0020and\u0020Settings\\mjones\\My\u0020Documents\\Visual\u0020Studio\u00202008\\Projects\\SeminarMailings\\
SccWebProject1 = true
SccProjectUniqueName1 = ..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\Development\\SeminarMailings
SccLocalPath1 = ..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..
SccProjectFilePathRelativizedFromConnection1 = Development\\SeminarMailings\\
SccProjectEnlistmentChoice1 = 2
EndGlobalSection
GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
EndGlobalSection
GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
{2951C6A1-AF82-40C6-9DD8-93E35E5135F6}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
{2951C6A1-AF82-40C6-9DD8-93E35E5135F6}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
EndGlobalSection
GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
HideSolutionNode = FALSE
EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```